# how to get the item of an array, selected in the select with svelte?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, svelte, svelte-3

I have the following formData object which has the properties that I read from the input and the select, but I don't really understand how to make the select only select the option I choose, since when submitting it sends all the objects of the users array and not the one selected in the select

```js
<script>

 let users_options = [
    {id:22, name: "lana"},
    {id:33,name:"John"}
    {id:45,name:"avril"}
]

let formData = {
    id:5,
    users: users_options
    name:"",
    email:""
}
    
    function send(){
        console.log(formData);
    }


</script>


<form on:submit|preventDefault={send}>

  <label>name</label> <br>
  <input type="text" 
  bind:value={formData.name}
  on:input={ e => (formData.name => e.target.value)}
  />
  
  <label>email</label>
  
  <input type="email" bind:value={formData.email}
  on:input={ e => (formData.email => e.target.value)}
  />

  <label>Select user</label><br>
  
  <select>
    {#each formData.users as item (item.id)}
      <option value={item.name}>{item.name}</option>
    
    {/each}
  
  </select>
  
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a variable to the `<select />` element to persist the selected option. Doing the same for the other form fields would simplify the code.

```html
<script>
    let users_options = [
        {id:22, name: "lana"},
        {id:33, name:"John"},
        {id:45, name:"avril"}
    ]

    let name
    let email
    let user
    
    function send(){
        const formData = {
            name,
            email,
            user
        }
        console.log(formData);
    }
</script>

<form on:submit|preventDefault={send}>
    <label>name</label> <br>
    <input type="text" bind:value={name} />

    <label>email</label>
    <input type="email" bind:value={email} />

    <label>Select user</label><br>
    <select bind:value={user}>
        {#each users_options as item (item.id)}
            <option value={item}>{item.name}</option>
        {/each}
    </select><br>

    <button type=submit>
        Submit
    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: the problem is that the user data must go like this, towards the api
{name: "name", ememail: "name@gmail.com", user: {id: 33, name: "avril"}

Comment: That's just a matter of changing the object format. Check my updated answer.

Comment: if(NOT_WANTED_OPTION){make user redo form selection}

Answer (score 0):

I really recommand you to have an object for the state of the form so that the `formData` object doesn't contain all the `users` but just the selected name. For that you can just have a simple `bind`:

```html
<script>
 let users_options = [
    {id:22, name: "lana"},
    {id:33,name:"John"},
    {id:45,name:"avril"}
]

let formData = {
    id:5,
    user: null,
    name:"",
    email:""
}
</script>


<form on:submit|preventDefault={send}>
  <select bind:value={formData.user}>
    {#each users_options as user}
      <option value={user.name}>{user.name}</option>
    {/each}
  </select>
</form>
```

Then when you send you object, you just have to find the right `user` object in `users_options`. In modern javascript it's really simple to achieve it with the help of `find`:

```js
function send() {
    console.log({
        ...formData,
        user: users_options.find(userOption => {
            return userOption.name === formData.user
        })
    });
}
```

So the final code look like  this:

```html
<script>

 let users_options = [
    {id:22, name: "lana"},
    {id:33,name:"John"},
    {id:45,name:"avril"}
]

let formData = {
    id:5,
    user: null,
    name:"",
    email:""
}
    
function send(){
    console.log({
        ...formData,
        user: users_options.find(userOption => {
            return userOption.name === formData.user
        })
    });
}
    
$: console.log(formData)


</script>


<form on:submit|preventDefault={send}>

  <label>name</label> <br>
  <input type="text" 
  bind:value={formData.name}
  on:input={ e => (formData.name = e.target.value)}
  />
  
  <label>email</label>
  
  <input type="email" bind:value={formData.email}
  on:input={ e => (formData.email = e.target.value)}
  />

  <label>Select user</label><br>
  
  <select bind:value={formData.user}>
    {#each users_options as user}
      <option value={user.name}>{user.name}</option>
    
    {/each}
  
  </select>
  
    <button type="submit">
        Submit
    </button>
</form>
```

Have a look at the [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/f3e84a3e7b104df092c733bda1bf2be0?version=3.31.0).